# Determine if an object is being accessed by more than one thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I'm getting sporadic EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes which I'm thinking has to do with multi-threading issues. (I tried profiling with Zombies, but the app doesn't crash when profiling). So I'm wondering if there is any sort of mechanism, for debugging purposes, to determine if an object is being simultaneously accessed by more than one thread? Maybe somehow print a log statement if that is the case?

Comment: More than likely what is happening is you are just accessing an object that has already been released. That is generally the result of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. That is also consistent with not crashing with zombies enabled. You are trying to access a `nil` object.

Comment: Also, it's a better approach to ***guard against*** it, not detect it.

Comment: Well first I wanted to see if my hypothesis was correct, since I'm not really sure what the issue is. But see the edit, I think it might have something to do with drawing.

Comment: Where are you drawing? If its in a context provided by UIGraphicsBeginImageContext its not thread save - so I assume this is a bitmap context you created using Quartz?

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext is not thread safe? I'm pretty sure it is. I got the idea from a WWDC 2012 video where they did just that on a background thread..

Comment: @MichaelBoselowitz: It's the most common *cause* of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, not result.

Comment: @MichaelBoselowitz: Also, sending a message to `nil` does not cause a crash. It is explicitly guaranteed by Objective-C to do nothing. Attempting to directly access instance variables of `nil` can cause a crash, but if you're doing that, you have worse problems. `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` suggests that the questioner is trying to use a deallocated object, not `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple and dirty method of telling if you are the only one executing on a thread would rely on unguarded static variables:

```
-(void)concurrentMethod {
    static NSThread *runningThread = nil;
    NSThread *myThread = [NSThread currentThread];
    if (runningThread != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Thread %@: running concurrently with %@", runningThread, myThread);
    }
    runningThread = myThread;

    ... // Do the useful stuff here

    if (runningThread != myThread) {
        NSLog(@"Thread %@: pre-empted by %@", myThread, runningThread);
    }
    runningThread = nil;
}
```

Comment: So if runningThread != myThread, does that mean two different threads tried to access the same object simultaneously?

Comment: @mohabitar When a thread enters your method, it checks the `runningThread` variable (which is `static`, and is therefore shared among all threads) to be `nil`. If it is, the thread sets it to its own ID; if it isn't, some other thread must have set it to a different ID. The thread overwrites the ID anyway, and proceeds to do the useful stuff. After that it checks if its ID has been overwritten, and finally restores the static back to `nil`.

Comment: @mohabitar `runningThread != myThread` means that while this thread was executing "useful stuff", another thread came along and started executing as well.

Comment: Ok so I'm getting a lot of log statements saying that thread was pre-empted by other thread, however, I'm still not entirely sure what that means. Is this a bad thing? Or does it depend on my setup?

Comment: @mohabitar A lot of "preempted" message confirms that your code gets executed concurrently a lot. It is not in itself a bug, as long as you planned for it. If you do not want concurrent execution of the method, add a `@synchronized { }` block around the entire method body. The log messages should go away. The crashes may or may not go, however: if they stay, it means that they were not caused only by concurrent execution.